# How can I get the task details (ID and Connector) within Kafka Connect Runtime

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create a custom connector and I want to log the task details (Connector and Task ID) within the task runtime. In the Task start and poll methods I want to log the task number and connector name. Is there any way I can get the program runtime context which provides the task details (Connector and Task ID).

Please note that the connector may have multiple tasks running parallel (tasks.max configuration) so I want to associate specific messages with the specific task which created it.

Answer (score 4):

Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) logging was added to Apache Kafka 2.3 and you can log this information by setting:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n
```

This gives you logs like this:

```
INFO [sink-elastic-orders-00|task-0] Using multi thread/connection supporting pooling connection manager (io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory:223)
INFO [sink-elastic-orders-00|task-0] Using default GSON instance (io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory:69)
```

ref: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-improvements-in-apache-kafka-2-3

Comment: Thanks, This is helpful for the logging aspect. But is it possible to get this information within the running connector using some java API.

Comment: @GrizzledDevArch It's a bit of a kludge, but you could get the value from the Log4J diagnostic context: `String connectorContext = MDC.get("connector.context");`

Answer (score 1):

A given [`Connector`](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/connector/Connector.html) has a `context` field, however I am not seeing in the API how you would get details about metadata of the running task